# How can I store data of decode JWT in nuxt?

Tags: jwt, nuxt.js, symfony4, lexikjwtauthbundle

I have pages with connexion and deconnexion to login on my nuxt app.

I use Symfony for the back and the librairy JWT for token authentification.

Here this is the code auth.js called when an user is login on my app. This works but I would like to store in my vuex the data into the token (I have the role and I would like to use it to display different things on page in function of the role). How can I do this ? Thanks for help

```js
import axios from "axios";
import jwtDecode from "jwt-decode";

export const login = async (data) => {
  const token = await axios
    .post(process.env.baseUrl + 'login_check', data)
    .then (response =>  response.data.token )

  window.localStorage.setItem("authToken", token)
  axios.defaults.headers["Authorization"] = "Bearer " + token;

}


export const logout = () => {
  window.localStorage.removeItem("authToken")

  delete axios.defaults.headers['Authorization'];
}


export const verifToken = () => {

  const token = window.localStorage.getItem("authToken");


  if (token ) {

    const jwtData = jwtDecode(token);


    if (jwtData.exp * 1000 > new Date().getTime()) //
    {
      axios.defaults.headers["Authorization"] = "Bearer " + token;
      //console.log("connexion axios OK")
      return true
    }
    else // if expired
    {
      logout();
    }

  }

  //if no token
  else {
    logout();
    console.log("no token")
  }
}
```

Comment: Check out the ``store`` section of nuxtjs docs here: https://nuxtjs.org/docs/directory-structure/store. Then you can use vuex-persistedstate as a plugin to store the token on browser with the help of vuex. The most easy way is to use auth.nuxt for the whole operation, though.

Comment: jwt-decode last publish is 2 years ago, is there any more recent library?